# Statistical model for variable that grows exponentially over time

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Suppose I am measuring an integer variable over time, so I have the measurements $m_1, m_2, ..., m_n$. I expect the actual variable (i.e. the phenomenon) to be growing exponentially over time at a constant growth rate, but when I measure the variable there's a noise component to it. For instance, we can imagine every sample m_i is actually sampled from a normal distribution whose mean value is growing exponentially over time. So m1, m2, ... are actually drawn from different - but related - distributions. How can I analyze such a model? I.e. how to find the maximum-likelihood estimator for the growth rate and the starting value? I think this must be a very basic scenario when dealing with exponential phenomena since there will always be a noise component to any measurement. But I haven't been able to find an article that discusses how to deal with it. If there are general mechanisms for treating combined distributions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's break this down.  Your outcome is an integer but you are choosing your likelihood to be normal (which in some circumstances is not an awful assumption to make).  Looks like you want to model

$$ y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\alpha \exp(\beta_1 t), \sigma^2) $$

I can offer some advice in R.  If you assume that the conditional mean is exponential but the noise is normal, you can either use `nls` in R or you can use `glm` with `family=gaussian(link='log')`.  Here is an example.

````r
library(tidyverse)

x = seq(0,10)
mu = exp(log(10) + x*log(2)/10)
#Integer outcome
y = rpois(length(mu), mu)

tibble(x, y) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = 'glm', method.args = list(family = gaussian(link = 'log')))

```
````

Comment: Hi Demetri... Thanks yes it looks right that this is my model. but what is the theory behind it? I.e. what is the MML estimators etc? Or can such models only be treated numerically? I am not sure I follow what the R code does... Is it sampling or is it parameters estimation?

Comment: You probably won't be able to find closed form solutions for the coefficients of this model.  You will have to find them numerically.